# How to construct a regex expression for username validation?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on constructing a PHP regex expression for a username validation that has the following constraints:

> -must be 10-16 characters long, with a combo of alphabetic, numeric, and atleast one special character (*&^-_$)
>   -can't start with a numeric or special character

CORRECTION: the last SIX digits must be a month/date birthday (`MMYYYY format`). In order to further validate the username, the month/date must show the username is over 18 - if not, the username will not validate. Thank you in advance for any assistance! I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Don't forget to show your attempted code

Comment: how the regex should be constructed really depends on what you want to do with it. You mentioned username validation, but what code / structure were you planning on implementing? this is vital knowledge for us to be able to deduce what you want to happen.

Comment: It's a PHP regex: here is my attempted code (it's very incorrect) (?=^.{10,16}$)^[a-z][\d]*[_$^&*]?[a-z0-9]+

Comment: Please don't significantly change your question. The "Correction" above imposes very different and much more complex conditions. You should accept an answer to this question, then post a new question with your additional conditions (if you can't figure it out on your own). You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You can do this with the following regex:

```
/(?=^.{10,16}$)(?=.+?[*&^_$-])[a-z].+?[01]\d{3}$/i
```

[Here's a demo with some unit tests.](https://regex101.com/r/qA6tV2/1)

## Explanation

- `/` delimiter
- `(?=^.{10,16}$)` ensures there are 10-16 characters, start to finish

  - `(?=` starts a lookahead group
  - `^` start of the string
  - `.{10,16}` ten to sixteen characters
  - `$` end of the string
  - `)` ends the lookahead group
- `(?=.+?[*&^_$-])` ensures there is at least one special character in the set `*&^_$-`, and it's not first

  - `(?=` starts a lookahead group
  - `.+?` one or more characters, non-greedy
  - `[*&^_$-]` any character in the set `*&^_$-` (note the order; you must put `-` first or last, or escape it as `\-`)
  - `)` ends the lookahead group
- `[a-z]` start with a letter
- `.+?` match any characters in a non-greedy fashion, giving back as needed
- `[01]\d{3}` match a `0` or `1` then 3 more digits
- `$` match the end of the string
- `/` closing delimiter
- `i` make the match case-insensitive

## Some Notes on Regex Construction

Note that there are multiple valid ways to do this. For pure efficiency, the solution above could be simplified somewhat to cut out a few steps for the processor.

But for readability, I like to go with something like the above. It's clear what each block, character set, or group does, which makes it readable and maintainable.

Something like `/^[a-z](?=.*?[*&^_$-])[a-z0-9*&^_$-]{5,11}[01]\d{3}$` is hard to read and understand. What if you want to allow a 17 character username? You have to do a bunch of math to determine that you should change `{5,11}` to `{5,12}`. Or if you decide to allow the character `#`, you'd have to add it in two places (which, by the way, means that the regex already violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

## Bonus: Why Your Attempt Failed

You said in a comment that you tried this:

```
(?=^.{10,16}$)^[a-z][\d]*[_$^&*]?[a-z0-9]+
```

The first part, `(?=^.{10,16}$)`, is fine. So is `^[a-z]`.

But `[\d]*` *only* matches zero or more digits; it wouldn't match a letter or special character. So, for example, `a&a...` would fail.

And `[_$^&*]?` only matches zero or one special characters. It would allow a username with *no* special characters to pass, but would fail one with 2 special characters.

`[a-z0-9]+` only matches those characters, and you omit your last-four-characters-must-be-digits requirement.

You might find [the explanation on regex101.com of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/lX4fA4/1) helpful. (Note: I have no affiliation with that site.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[*&^_$-])[\w*&^$-]{5,11}[01]\d{3}$
```

Regex Breakup:

```
^                  # Line start
[a-zA-Z]           # # match an alhpabet
(?=.*[*&^_$-])     # lookahead to ensure there is at least one special char
[\w*&^$-]{5,11}    # match 5 to 11 of allowed chars
[01]\d{3}          # match digits 0/1 followed by 3 digits
$                  # Line end
```

I used quantifier `{5,11}` because one char is matches at start and 4 are being matched in the end thus taking out 5 positions from desired `{10,16}` lengths.